# How do I recreate a nested list from a long string of information in Python?

Tags: python, encryption, nested-forms, nested-lists

I have an algorithm that encrypts a string into a long list of numbers using an encryption key that the program generates. It works by encrypting one word at a time and putting it into a nested list.

For example:

```
"4 3 1 4 5 5 2 4 6 2 3"
```

This would be two words because the first number is a four meaning the next four numbers represent four letters of a word. Then after those 5 numbers, there is a five meaning that the next five numbers represent five letters of a word.

I don't know how to convert:

```
"4 3 1 4 5 5 2 4 6 2 3"
```

Into the nested list:

```
[[3,1,4,5], [2,4,6,2,3] ]
```

I have tried many concepts but can't seem to figure anything out. Any ideas?

Here is the encryption code if you need it:

```
import string
import random

def generateKey():
    return(''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(2)))

def encrypt(message, encryptionKey = list(generateKey())):
    print(''.join(encryptionKey))
    message = message.split(' ')

    array = []

    z = 0
    for word in message:
        array.append([])

    for word in message:
        array[z].append(len(word)*ord(encryptionKey[0]))
        for letter in word:
            array[z].append(ord(letter)*ord(encryptionKey[1]))
        z += 1

    z = 0
    for row in array:
        for _set in row:
            print(str(_set) + ' ', end='')
        print('\n')

    return(array) #Even though it returns a list, this data will be transferred from one person to another via one long string of text
```

Comment: I ran your `encrypt` function with the parameter `4 3 1 4 5 5 2 4 6 2 3` and I got `[[82, 4212], [82, 4131], [82, 3969], [82, 4212], [82, 4293], [82, 4293], [82, 4050], [82, 4212], [82, 4374], [82, 4050], [82, 4131]]` , Is that correct output ? I mean where is the problem actually ? in the format of output or in the logic ?

Comment: I was giving a simplified example when I used "4 3 1 4 5 5 2 4 6 2 3" @Anmol_uppal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your encryption function is well-formed, this should produce the output you requested. Basically it works by creating a shared iterator that will keep its place between calls of the subroutine.

```
def sentence(text):
    iter_text = iter(text.split())
    # split text on spaces and create a single iterator from it

    def word(i_text, num_chars):
        """Helper function to return a list of the num_chars length
        pulled out of the iterator i_text"""

        return [next(i_text) for _ in range(num_chars)]
        # [int(next(i_text)) ... ] for your literal output, but since you're
        # encrypting as a string it seems more consistent to DECRYPT to a string

    return [word(iter_text, int(ch)) for ch in iter_text]
```

Example:

```
>>> text = '4 3 1 4 5 5 2 4 6 2 3'
>>> result = sentence(text)
>>> print(result)
[['3', '1', '4', '5'], ['2', '4', '6', '2', '3']]
```